# Can not import Jupyter notebook into Data Science Experience: "Something went wrong. Could not create a notebook. Missing mandatory property 'content'

Tags: data-science-experience

When creating a new notebook from file I get this error message (tried it with 3 files):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you are uploading an invalid ipynb file (missing the content property in JSON).

For further help, please contact DSX support, and attach the notebook file you are trying to upload.